# copy symlinks with rsync

Tags: rsync, symlink

When I'm trying to backup a disk with rsync, symbolic links are not resolved correctly.

For example:

```
media 
└disk1
  ├folder1
  │ └folder2 (symlink to /media/disk1/folder2)
  └folder2
```

After `rsync -a /media/disk1/. /media/disk2` disk2 will look like this:

```
media 
└disk2
  ├folder1
  │ └folder2 (symlink to /media/disk1/folder2) <-- should be "disk2"
  └folder2
```

What I want is a solution to make symlinks "relative" or that rsync automatically adjust the link reference. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use relative symlinks instead:

```
media 
└disk1
  ├folder1
  │ └folder2 (symlink to ../folder2)
  └folder2
```

When copied it will be the same, and since that is relative to the location, it will serve the same purpose in `disk2`.

In case that's not clear, the idea is:

```
cd /media/disk1/folder1
rm folder2
ln -s ../folder2 folder2
```

This last command is different than `ln -s /media/disk1/folder2 folder2`; in the first case the content of the link is a relative path, in the second it is absolute.  You want to use relative paths, not absolute ones, in this case.